# Using Weka on command line to generate cluster assignment arff file

Tags: cluster-analysis, weka, arff

On the explorer in weka you can perform clustering on data then use the visualisation to save a new arff file with the cluster assignments as attributes.

Is there a way to do this automatically by calling executables on the command line?

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else is having this problem, you can try using weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.AddCluster. The -W argument should contain your clustering algorithm and you can use the -i and -o as you would with any other filter to save your new arff.