# WEKA: How to save clusterer results to arff?

Tags: weka, arff

I want to save the `clusterer` (Cobweb) results to an `arff` file, but I can't seem to figure it out. I know how to save the results from **GUI**, but I cant figure out how to do it from my `java` code, even after searching for a couple of hours.

Here is my code.

```
ArffLoader loader = new ArffLoader();
loader.setFile(new File(sourceFile));
Instances structure = loader.getStructure();

Cobweb cw = new Cobweb();
cw.buildClusterer(structure);
Instance current;
while ((current = loader.getNextInstance(structure)) != null)
     cw.updateClusterer(current);
cw.updateFinished();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Weka on command line to generate cluster assignment arff file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486767/using-weka-on-command-line-to-generate-cluster-assignment-arff-file)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using

```
weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.AddCluster
```

which adds the cluster assignment to your data.